# Resample/reindex sensor data

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do some data processing to sensor data (about 300 different sensors). This is an example of the raw data from a temperature sensor:

```
 "2018-06-30T13:17:05.986Z" 30.5
 "2018-06-30T13:12:05.984Z" 30.3
 "2018-06-30T13:07:05.934Z" 29.5
 "2018-06-30T13:02:05.873Z" 30.3
 "2018-06-30T12:57:05.904Z" 30
```

I want to resample the data to smooth datetimes:

```
13:00:00
13:05:00
13:10:00
...
```

I have written some code that works, but is incredibly slow when used on bigger files. My code just upsamples all the data to 1 sec via linear interpolation. and downsamples afterwards to the requested frequency.

Is there a faster method to achieve this?

EDIT:
sensor data is written into a database and my code loads data from an arbitrary time intervall from the database

EDIT2: My working code

```
upsampled = dataframe.resample('1S').asfreq()
upsampled = upsampled.interpolate(method=method, limit=limitT) # ffill or bfill for some sensors 
resampled = upsampled.astype(float).resample(str(sampling_time) + 'S').mean() # for temperature 
resampled = upsampled.astype(float).resample(str(sampling_time) + 'S').asfreq() # for everything else
```

Comment: Since this is sensor data, is it safe to assume this is real-time data feeding into your code?  Or is the data being written into a file or database and you're reading from that?

Comment: sensor data is written into a database and my code loads data from an arbitrary time intervall from the database

Comment: I guess error is because you haven't specified the resampling based on which column or index of df . Try setting a index or specifying column for resampling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first set the index for the dataframe as the column with timestamps, and then use `resample()` method to bring it to every 1sec or every 5min interval data.

For example:

```
temp_df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv',header=None)
temp_df.columns = ['Timestamps','TEMP']
temp_df = temp_df.set_index('Timestamps') #set the timestamp column as index
temp_re_df = temp_df.TEMP.resample('5T').mean()
```

You can set the period as argument to the `resample()` i.e T - min , S - sec , M - month, H - hour etc. and also apply a function like `mean()` or `max()` or `min()` to consider the down-sampling method.

P.S : This is given that that your timestamp are in datetime format of pandas. Else use `pd.to_datetime(temp_df['Timestamps'],unit='s')` to convert to datetime index column

Comment: Please do vote if answer is helpful. Happy coding :)

Comment: hi, just saw the answer, thanks! i will evaluate if it works in all my use cases but it looks promising

Comment: Sure ! great. Go for it.